# Android AutoCompleteTextview OnClick

Tags: android

```
public class getLocationName extends Activity {

AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;
PlacesTask placesTask;
ParserTask parserTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getlocationname);

    atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
    atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);      
    atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
        {
            AutoCompleteTextView a=(AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
            Log.d("TAG", a.getText().toString());
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
        }

    });
     atvPlaces.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              atvPlaces.showDropDown();
            return false;
        }
    });
    atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
            placesTask = new PlacesTask();              
            placesTask.execute(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }
    }); 
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);                

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url 
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
 }  

// Fetches all places from GooglePlaces AutoComplete Web Service
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=sdhdjsdsddsldsdjs";

        String input="";

        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       


        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service in background
            data = downloadUrl(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Creating ParserTask
        parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }       
}


/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {            

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);


        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {


            String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView            
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);             

            // Setting the adapter
            atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);


    }           
}    


}
```

Logcat:

```
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569): Process: com.example.remindme, PID: 3569
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at com.example.remindme.getLocationName$1.onItemClick(getLocationName.java:53)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:902)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1192)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-02 08:17:23.151: E/AndroidRuntime(3569):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On Click event I want to get the clicked item but it is showing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to call `findViewById()` in your `OnItemClickListener` for `atvPlaces`.

As the `findViewById()` fails to find the view it returns `null` and you will get a `NullPointerException` when you try to access the object (i.e. when you call the `a.getText()` method)

You already have a reference to the `AutoCompleteTextView` in your `atvPlaces` variable. So there is no need to redefine one (especially on each item click!)

The code below fixes this:

```
atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
        {

            Log.d("TAG", atvPlaces.getText().toString());
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Kotlin` thats how you can use `setOnItemClickListener`

```
atvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id -> 
      ...
}
```